# Multiple column key or multiple column unique

Tags: mysql

If I want to make sure that there are unique columns by `user_id` and `notification_id`. Should I use `UNIQUE` constraint on that two columns and (eventualy) set `id` as `PRIMARY KEY` or set these two columns as `PRIMARY KEY` and remove `id` column?
This is how table should look:

```
Column             Type       
----------------------------------
id                 int(11)    
user_id            int(11)    
notification_id    int(11)    
col3               varchar(255)
...
```

Comment: use UNIQUE constraint on two columns(user_id and notification_id) and set id as PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: Set the composite unique index to `user_id, notification_id`. LEAVE `id` as primary key. If you omit it, InnoDB will create a hidden key that's 8 bytes long so it can use this info for efficient writes. If you use MySQL, you want to have `auto_increment` primary key in almost all cases. It's also useful to have a single column helping you uniquely distinguish a record.

Comment: Thank you Mjh for detailed explanation, it helps me alot.

Comment: Even when accepted answer is in favor of additional ID, the comments explain why is preferred the composited key. You still need make a decision, but at least will be an informed decision.